# Австосохранение в черновики

Tags: ajax, php

Привет Всем.
Есть такой вопрос: как можно реализовать автосохранение в черновики?
Например, есть сайт с разными статьями, и тут надо добавить одну статью. Пользователь вводит, а в это время с самого начала действий пользователя статья пока сохраняется в черновики. Как это можно реализовать без использования готовых CMS?

Comment: А как можно сделать условие, чтоб ajax начал отправлять данные сначала после начала ввода, а потом уже по счетчику времени?

Comment: Можно еще использовать события onKeyUp, onKeyPress, onKeyDown.

Comment: Лучше change(), как по мне...

Comment: @jackrv, change срабатывает в момент потери фокуса элементом формы, т.е. начавший писать и отошедший на час человек не будет замечен системой вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Во время написания раз в несколько секунд отправляется ajax-запрос с текстом.
В PHP данные сохраняются в сессию.
При необходимости также отправляется ajax, и выводятся данные из сессии.